# Fixed position of bottom content until top content height expands

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a css-only solution that will accomplish what's illustrated below. The area of concern here is the content to the right of the image.

[image: Fig. 1]

**Ex 1: Minimal top content:** When there is only one line of top content (shown as "hi" here) keep the bottom content (everything below) flushed to the bottom as shown.

[image: Fig. 2]

**Ex 2: More top content:** More top content shown here, but still not enough to warrant any positional shift in the elements below it.

[image: Fig. 3]

**Ex 3: Lots of top content:** Obviously, the bottom elements need to shift now.

Basically, the code is currently just two `<div>` elements stacked on top of each other.

```
<div id="top">Lorem ipsum...</div>
<div id="bottom" style="margin-top:30px;">...</div>
```

It's easy to set the bottom elements in a fixed position, but I'd like them to shift down when it makes sense to do so (as shown in example 3). Any possible css-only solutions to accomplish this precise behavior?

Comment: Used to min-height #top{min-height:100px;} ..........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `min-height`  for example

```
#top{min-height:80px;}
```

Comment: Nice and simple. Thanks Abdul.